Earthing and Earth's voltage
I'm looking into earthing within my topic of electric fields and i'm really getting confused with the aspect of earth having zero potential difference. My understanding of potential difference is that it is the work done to move a charge between two points against an electric field. Taking this definition into account, how can somebody say that earths potential difference is zero if voltage is supposed to be measured between two points?

IDK about electric fields as such, but in Electronics and Electrical Engineering, it is common practice to assign a value to the voltage at some single point. And, what that really means is, it's the voltage between the point in question, and some implicit reference point, which is called "ground," or "Earth," or "neutral" depending on the context. Obviously, according to that convention, the voltage at Earth must be zero because the voltage between Earth and itself could not have any other value.

Related question: Why is the Earth considered an infinite electron source or sink? A lightning rod is effective when there is good electric contact with the soil that it is embedded in. With sufficient electric contact the Earth will act as a sink for all of the current of a lightning strike. Big as a lightning strike is, it has nowhere the capacity to change the potential of the Earth. The charge spreads, and it all evens out.


My understanding of potential difference is that it is the work done to move a charge between two points against an electric field. Taking this definition into account, how can somebody say that earths potential difference is zero if voltage is supposed to be measured between two points?

We don't say that. We say "Earth's potential is zero", not "Earth's potential difference is zero".
Potential difference is something measured between two points, not a property of a single point, so (taking the Earth as a single point or an equipotential region) it wouldn't make sense to talk about "the potential difference of the Earth" any more than it would make sense to talk about "the potential difference at the origin of my coordinate system". To have a potential difference we must consider two points and take the difference between the potentials at those two points.
We can choose to say the potential of the Earth is zero because we can choose any point in space we like to have a fixed potential and it won't change the potential difference between any two points in the system. Using the Earth as the reference potential is convenient in many cases because we often do our experiments in labs that are close to the surface of the Earth, and choosing zero as its potential is convenient because it means that the potential of any other point in the system can be determined by measuring its potential difference from the Earth.

You can put potential Zero at any point or a conducting object. Earth has no potential difference, only a potential which you assign to it, often 0.  If you connect for example the plus pole of a 3V Battery to earth "earthing" it, then the potential difference to the other pole is 3 V, if you give earth the potential 0 the other pole of the batterie has  potential -3V.

As you point out, voltages represent the difference in potential between two points. To define that difference relative to the rest of the world, one of the two points can be assigned a reference voltage of zero and all subsequent measurements of voltages within that system are then conveniently expressed as differences between the measurement point and the zero reference.
That zero reference is usually named the ground potential (in USA usage) or earth potential (in UK parlance) and is set equal to zero in all calculations.
In engineering usage, for example, one can say that connecting the high voltage terminal of a charged capacitor to ground will cause the charge on the capacitor to be dumped or discharged, leaving the potential difference between the two plates of the capacitor equal to zero- so the capacitor and the rest of the circuit to which it is connected can be safely touched without risk of electrocution.
